# While using HTTPS protocol, who encrypts the message, the Browser or the Network Card?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, network-protocols

I am reading about WCF Transport Security and I get a plethora of doubts in my mind because I have less network knowledge.

They say, Transport security is good to use only when there is direct communication between client and server. There should be no intermediaries.

First of all I want to know, what are these intermediaries ? According to me, they are the routers sitting in between, which relay the messages to next hop, and are not complete computer systems, on which somebody can sit and intercept the messages.

I have other doubts also regarding this topic, which I will ask once I receive the answer for this one.

Comment: One other thing "intermediaries" might mean is proxies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No routers are not intermediaries in this scenario. Routers, switches and other network infrastructure devices operates on lower layers of ISO/OSI or TCP/IP network protocol stacks.

Intermediaries are in this case gateways, load balancers or reverse proxies. From the client point of view the gateway or reverse proxy is the host of the service but it doesn't have to be. It can be just entry point into some corporate network which will forward the message to the real host (server hosting the service) hidden inside the corporate network.

The difference between message and transport security is that transport security ends at the gateway - for client it is a destination and client opens connection to that destination. The connection is point to point and transport security cannot be maintained among multiple connections (transport security starts at one side of the connection and ends on the other side). Message security in turn is end to end it means that message contains security as part of its content and gateways just forward secured messages. Only the real destination (real host of the service) should be able to decrypt those messages.

> While using HTTPS protocol, who encrypts the message, the Browser or the Network Card?

Again HTTPS is upper layer protocol - it is not responsibility of the network card to use it. Some programming API or OS infrastructure is responsible for creating HTTPS connection. Browser just calls this API.

Comment: Can the gateways, load balancers and reverse proxies be at a place where original host does not have any rights ? If they are in the same corporate network of the owners of original host, then whats the point of sniffing at the message ? Because the message is intended ultimately for them only ?

Comment: Generally yes. Gateway can be under control of different subject. It can still be the same corporation but another division or what so ever. What is the point of sniffing message? The most attacks comes from inside of the company (or with insider knowledge).

Comment: `for client it is a destination and client opens connection to that destination.` - When I send a GET request for a URL say `http://abc.com` then the IP Address for `abc.com` is the gateway or load balancer or reverse proxy ? and then it sends the request to orignial host ?

Comment: If my above guess is correct, then it means if we do not have any (gateway or load balancer or proxy) then we can use Transport Security over internet also ? (Sorry, if my questions are ridiculous, but I want to learn perfectly, so I will ask everything I have in my mind)

Comment: Yes, both your assumptions are correct. If you have a server hosting your service with public IP exposed directly to internet and DNS `http://abc.com` points to your server the HTTPS connection will be opened between client and your server directly.

Comment: If I have public IP exposed and DNS `abc.com` points to my server, then is it 100% sure that the connection will be direct between client and my server even if they are thousands of miles apart ?

Comment: I mean the Client will access the server using services of some ISP, will that ISP not have any Computers which will be in-between and can intercept the messages, though on the server's side we have direct connection ?

Comment: Yes you will have "direct" connection to the server. That is point of SSL/TLS. Your client will connect to the server and start SSL handshake where the client validate that it communicates with expected server (= it validate that it trusts the certificate) and it establish secure connection.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2895/discussion-between-puneet-dudeja-and-ladislav-mrnka)